# Why is UnknownHostException: downloads.typesafe.com when running activator ui?

Tags: typesafe-activator

I am getting the following exception after starting `activator ui` from command line.

```
Checking for a newer version of Activator (current version 1.2.2)...
   ... our current version 1.2.2 looks like the latest.
Found previous process id: 2988
FOUND REPO = activator-local @ file:////C:/shakti/scala/typesafe-activator-1.2.2
/activator-1.2.2/repository
Play server process ID is 5712
[info] play - Application started (Prod)
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /127.0.0.1:8888
[ERROR] [06/15/2014 05:46:13.851] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [ActorSystem(default)] Failed to download http://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/index/v2/index-07064250cfd1cc2444f19c731541332ccf93bc13.zip: sbt.TranslatedIOException: Error opening http://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/index/v2/index-07064250cfd1cc2444f19c731541332ccf93bc13.zip: java.net.UnknownHostException: downloads.typesafe.com
[INFO] [06/15/2014 05:46:13.860] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://default/user/template-cache] Unable to check remote server for template updates.
[INFO] [06/15/2014 05:46:19.155] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://default/user/home-socket-1] Firing up web socket
```

What could be the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you check again? Could be that it's an interim issue. Also, can you open http://downloads.typesafe.com and see if it's resolvable?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski - Yeah seems to be an intermittent issue. It is working now

Comment: Could you *please* delete the question, then? It adds no value to the tag and I want to keep it as clean as possible. Unless you object...Thanks!

Comment: Please don't delete the question. I am sure someone will face a similar problem in future and at least he will not panic if he sees it .It can be an intermittent issue due to network problem, but let it be there for future reference.

Comment: Deal! Don't forget to accept your answer, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems it was an intermittent issue due to some network problem. It is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this prolem using ./activator ui instead using activator ui on linux